# CountDownTimer freezes UI when trying to reproduce sound

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to reproduce the beep.wav sound each second from 3 to 1 , for example, reproduce 3 , 2, and 1 the beep sound, and then when finish reproduce the beependsound.

For some reason only the beependsound is playing but when reaching second 3 it seems the ui freezes for a sec and then the numbers decrease fast to 0

```
private void stopPlaying(){
        if(mp!=null){
            try {
                mp.reset();
                mp.prepareAsync();
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp=null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startCountDown() {

        aCounter = new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                if (Math.round((float) millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f) != secondsLeft) {
                    countDownTxt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    secondsLeft = Math.round((float) millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f);
                    countDownTxt.setText(String.valueOf(secondsLeft));
                }

                if (secondsLeft <= 3) {
                    countDownTxt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.beep);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                secondsLeft = 0;
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.beepend);
                mp.start();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        aCounter.cancel();
                        startCountDown();
                    }
                }, 1000);

            }
        };
        aCounter.start();
    }
```

I spect this to work as described above, any hint ?

Comment: It seems like you're doing a lot of work every 1/10 of a second for the last 3 seconds. Maybe you could change the CountDownTimer() second parameter to 1000, so the onTick() will be called only once per second?

Comment: yes but if I do that it will skip from 2 to 0 with no such presition

Comment: Do some of the work on another thread..use an aynctask ND just return to play the sound on each onTick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaPlayer.create()` can be a fairly expensive call. Consider what happens if it takes approximately 100ms (or even more):

1. The timer calls `onTick()`.
2. `onTick()` blocks for about 100ms inside `MediaPlayer.create()`.
3. `mp` starts playing, and `onTick()` returns. (So far, so good!)
4. Immediately, the timer realizes another `onTick()` call is due! The last one started over 100ms ago!
5. `onTick()` is called again, almost immediately. Very quickly, it reaches the `stopPlaying()` call. But you only *started* playing about 1ms ago!

This leads to a situation where your timer spends all its time in `MediaPlayer.create()`, and almost no time actually playing the sound.

Note that, with the code as written, it will attempt to play the sound approximately 30 times in the last 3 seconds of the countdown (since the ticks are ideally 100ms apart). If your intent was to play the sound only 3 times, you may want to move your second `if` block to inside the first. That way, you only attempt play when `secondsLeft` actually changes. This will actually ameliorate the original problem, and you may not need any further changes.

But if you want to optimize further, note that you can prepare `mp` in advance -- say, when the app starts up -- and simply reuse it: Instead of `release()`-ing it each time, just `stop()` it, and `prepare()` it (and *don't* `reset()` it). That'll leave it ready for the next play. You could even create a separate `MediaPlayer` just for `beepend`, and you could prepare them both during app initialization.